# WPF: ItemSource not showing any item

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

The WPF piece of code is quite simple:

```
<telerik:RadGridView Name="AnalisiKey" 
                              AutoGenerateColumns="True"
                                         Margin="10,273,694,59" 
                              d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewModels:FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole}" 
                              ClipboardCopyMode="All" SelectionMode="Extended" SelectionUnit="Mixed">
      <!--<telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn  x:Name="Keyword" Header="Keyword" Language="it-it" DataMemberBinding="{Binding (viewModels:KeyFreq.Keyword)}" />
        <telerik:GridViewDataColumn x:Name="FreqNelDocum" Header="FreqNelDocum" Language="it-it" UniqueName="FreqNelDocum"/>
      </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>-->
    </telerik:RadGridView>
```

As well as the ViewModel

```
class FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel : MarkupExtension
  {
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) => this;

    public List<KeyFreq> ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole { get; set; } = new List<KeyFreq>();
  }
```

And the piece of code where the ItemSource is populated:

```
 private void MostroRisultatiSuGriglia(List<KeyFreq> singole,
          List<KeyFreq> doppie, bool excludeUnfrequentKeys)
        {
          var dataContext = ((FrequentKeywordFinderViewModel)this.DataContext);
          var itemCollectionViewSourceSingole = dataContext.ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole;

          singole = CalcolaTfIdf(StopWordsUtil.FrequenzaKeywords, singole);

            dataContext.ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole.AddRange(singole.Where(s => s.FreqNelDocum > 1).ToList());
            itemCollectionViewSourceDoppie.Source = doppie.Where(s => s.FreqNelDocum > 1).ToList();              

        }
```

With Snoop I can delve into the datagrid.ItemSource and see the items. But they don't appear in the datagrid. Any suggestion?

[image]

Comment: Not clear what MarkupExtension derives from, but (1) your ViewModel class should derive from INotifyPropertyChanged, and (2) your ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole  setter should invoke the PropertyChanged event and (3) your ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole should be an ObservableCollection rather than a List, since you populate it in an action distinct from its construction.

Comment: @Zenilogix: thank you very much. Can you convert it to an answer? Then I will add some extra code or screenshot to complete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A key point to be aware of when using binding is that the control doesn't get updated from bound properties unless and until it's notified that the values have changed. There are two basic ways to implement this notification:

1. Inherit your ViewModel from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invoke the `PropertyChanged` event whenever your property value changes. This approach is suitable for most situations, including numerical and string properties bound to controls such as `TextBlock` and `TextBox`.
2. Use `ObservableCollection` for collections bound to the `ItemsSource` property (for controls which have an `ItemsSource` property).

Controls are aware of the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface and the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface underlying `ObservableCollection`, and listen for the appropriate `PropertyChanged` and `CollectionChanged` events.

Guidelines for selecting the appropriate technique are as follows:

- If the property value in the ViewModel is set before the control's `DataContext` has been set to the ViewModel and never subsequently changes, you actually don't need to use the `PropertyChanged` notification at all, because the control will see the intended property value when the ViewModel is bound.
- If you are binding to a property for which the value will be intially assigned or will change *after* the `DataContext` has been set to the ViewModel, the ViewModel must inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the property setter must invoke the `PropertyChanged` event, otherwise the control will never be aware that the property value has changed.
- If you are binding a collection to control's `ItemsSource` property, you need to consider the above, but you also need to consider how and when you are populating or updating the collection's contents.
- If you are creating and populating a collection such as a list, then setting a ViewModel's property (which is bound to a control's `ItemsSource` property) and never modifying the collection's contents (although you may later assign the ViewModel property to different collection), the ViewModel must inherit from `INotifyPropertyChanged` and the collection property setter must invoke the `PropertyChanged` event. In this scenario, you actually don't need to consider ObservableCollection; you can use any desired collection type in your ViewModel.
- If you are modifying your collection's contents while it is bound to a control's `ItemsSource` property, `CollectionChanged` events are required for the control to update correctly; the easiest way to accomplish this is to use an `ObservableCollection` in your ViewModel; it will automatically raise `CollectionChanged` events as items are added or removed.

These are basic guidelines that should help to identify and resolve the most common/most likely problems when using binding.

Typical property binding:

```
public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _myString;
    public string MyString
    {
        get => _myString;
        set
        {
            _myString = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(MyString));
        }
    }
}
```

In your case, you might only need to change `ItemCollectionViewSourceSingole` from `List<KeyFreq>` to `ObservableCollection<KeyFreq>` because you initialize the empty collection in the ViewModel constructor and only add items later.